# AppExchange partner linking error

Tags: appexchange, partner-portal, partner

I'm trying to connect my Salesforce partnership to my AppExchange profile so I can publish an app. When I visit https://appexchange.salesforce.com/publisherProfile# and then select the **Change Partnership** option it pops open a login form asking for the Partnerforce.com account. However, when I try and use that account it shows me this error:

Please correct the following error(s):

```
We cannot find a partnership matching the credentials you entered.Please try again and if you continue to experience this problem please log a case in the Salesforce.com Partner Portal .
```

When I click on the **Register to become a partner** link it says I'm already a partner! How do I get it to recognize that I'm a partner so I can complete the linking step?

Comment: Can you login to the salesforce partner portal ok using the same credentials?